# Residue of $\frac{dz}{w^3}$ on the riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let compact riemannian surface X satisfy the equation $w^3=z(z-1)(z-2)$.

Let $p \in X$ be the point where $w=0, z=1$.

Compute

$Res_p(\frac{dz}{w^3}) $

By implicit function theorem, I see, that since $\frac{d(w^3 - z(z-1)(z-2)}{dz}$ is not zero at $p$, then the complement variable $w$
 is a coordinate.

What does the differential form $dz$ mean if z is not a coordinate at $p$?

Please, give me a hint or a useful book about the problem.

Comment: Given any meromorphic function $f$ on $X$, we can define the differential $df$; $z$ is a meromorphic function, so we can define $dz$. If you pick a coordinate $t$ at $p$ (I think you can take $t = w$ to be a coordinate at your $p$), then there is a meromorphic function $g$ such that $dz = g(t) \, dt$ in a neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: Dear Lada:  in English $X$ is called a Riemann surface (=риманова поверхность in Russian) and not a Riemannian manifold, which is a differential manifold endowed with a suitable metric and corresponds to the Russian римановое многообразие.

Comment: Thank you, Georges Elencwajg!

Comment: It was my pleasure, dear Lada. And welcome to this site, on which I hope to see you often in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right that at the point $p$ the variable $w$ is a local  coordinate.
Let us make a slight change of coordinates and put $u=z-1$, so that $u(p)=w(p)=0$ and $X$ has equation $$w^3=u^3-u \quad (\ast)$$  Your differential form is then $\eta=\frac{dz}{w^3}=\frac{du}{w^3}$.
Since $(\ast)$ implies that $3w^2dw=(3u^2-1)du$ and thus that $du=\frac {3w^2dw}{3u^2-1}$, we see that $$\eta=\frac{du}{w^3}=\frac {3dw}{w(3u^2-1)}$$ Since $w$ is a local coordinate at $p$ and since $(3u^2-1)(p)=-1$ ,we obtain the desired  result$$  \operatorname {Res}_p(\eta)=\frac {3}{-1}=-3$$

Comment: Is it right that $Res_p \frac{dw}{w}$ is equal to 1  just like $Res_0 \frac{dz}{z}$ is equal  to 1 on the complex plane?

Comment: Dear Lada, yes it is absolutely right **if $w$ is a local coordinate at $p$**, which is indeed the case here.